# Only 5 simultaneously users with PPTP VPN?

Tags: windows, vpn, windows-server-2008-r2

we have a windows 2008 R2 standard server which job is to accept incoming VPN connections via PPTP.

it seems to work fine, but the moment the 6th user try to connect, we get the following error:

> ERROR_VPN_DISCONNECT 807 The network connection between your computer
>   and the VPN server was interrupted. This can be caused by a problem in
>   the VPN transmission and is commonly the result of internet latency or
>   simply that your VPN server has reached capacity.

where do we find out how to increase the amount of simultaneously users?, I read somewhere that we  can have over 100 connected clients at the same time, when I created this server, I did the following :

1. Network & sharing -> Network adapters ->
2. File -> new incoming connections
3. now I tried to choose and create users here, but we have a domain controller which seems to override this, so the domain users works

after this I was able to connect atleast 5 clients...

how and where do I increase the "capacity"?

Comment: Do you not need to have Client Access Licenses for more than 5 concurrent users? I thought this was for Terminal Services/Remote Desktop but it may affect VPNs as well.

Comment: You either need CALs for every user, or you have to operate the VPN in anonymous mode (no security, probably *not* what you want).

Comment: thanks, but how do I check the CAL's, we are a Microsoft partner. but unsure what this will give us, and or how to increase the cals, anonymous wont be a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after not finding the reason why only 5 can be online at anyone time with the "New incoming connection" under network adapters, I finally managed to get the routing and remote access to work, now I get 50 connections which is good enough :)